# Cannot build cordova project successfully error while executing ant debug command

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans-7

I was having an error that is Camera not successful invoked on first try (click) so I tried this solution   on stackoverflow [Phonegap(3.0.0) Camera not successful on first try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650715/phonegap3-0-0-camera-not-successful-on-first-try).
I followed the steps as mentioned in the answer removed android  by **cordova platform remove android** then I run the second command **cordova platform add android** ;

Now when I use netbeans to run the cordova application on cordova android decvice this error occurs:

```
  exec: ant debug -f "/var/www/mobile/platforms/android/build.xml"

   [ 'ant debug -f "/var/www/mobile/platforms/android/build.xml"',
 { [Error: Command failed: 
  BUILD FAILED
  /var/www/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error       occurred while executing this line:
  /var/www/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed;   see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 8 seconds
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null },
  'Buildfile: /var/www/mobile/platforms/android/build.xml\n\n-set-mode-check:\n\n-set-debug-files:\n\n-check-env:\n [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0\n [checkenv] 
 .

 .

 .**LONG TEXT which I removed from the post **

 .

  \nBUILD FAILED\n/var/www/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720:   

 The following error occurred while executing this line:\n/var/www/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64- 20130917/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: 
 Compile failed; see the compiler error output for   details.\n\nTotal time: 8 seconds\n' ]

 Error executing "ant debug -f "/var/www/mobile/platforms/android/build.xml"": 
 BUILD FAILED
 /var/www/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following   error occurred while executing this line:
 /var/www/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed;  see the compiler error output for details.

 Total time: 8 seconds


 child_process.spawn(/var/www/mobile/platforms/android/cordova/build,[]) = 2

 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
 Error: An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "/var/www/mobile/platforms/android/build.xml"": 
 BUILD FAILED
/var/www/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 8 seconds


at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/compile.js:65:22)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
/var/www/mobile/nbproject/build.xml:256: exec returned: 8
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 minutes 36 seconds)
```

any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 16):

I was having a similar issue. I ran `ant debug -f "/path/to/project/build.xml"` from a separate terminal. It displayed a more specific description of the error (which for me wast that there was a space in the project name). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554965/error-building-android-app-with-cordova-3-1-cli) also notes:

> config.xml can't have a widget id with number as a first character
>   after a dot. For example: com.42myapp.test or com.myapp.42test won't
>   work as well as 42com.myapp.test. It will trigger an error from the
>   compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me, I had tried to a put a "#" as the author website link in one of the config.xml's, and also had some old Java file I edited deep into the platforms/Android directory that was some experimental code I was trying before that caused the build to fail. Fixing those made the build successful.

Comment: Unbelievable. Many hours of life gone!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issues when i started using the CLI to build apps using cordova and started checking the internet for solutions. While i was at it, i discovered the following things that may help you or anyone else facing the same problem can take some hints from this:

These are some very basic checks that you need to take 
1. make sure you have all the required sdk's in place (ANT, Java, Android) and is available when you use these commands on the terminal/command `$ ant` `$ java` `$ adt`. if any of these commands are not found, then you need to get it installed or get the class paths fixed.

1. make sure your project path does not have spaces. i.e. do not have spaces or special characters in directory names. this issue seems to have been fixed on latest versions of cordova and phonegap, but either cases it is a good practice to follow as ant and java paths could be dependent on the folder names you make.
2. use -d or -v to get extra debug information on the build process to know where and what is causing the issue. `$ cordova build android -d` or `$ cordova build android -v`
3. Make sure you dont use "#" as the link attribute of author tag in the cordova config.xml on the root of the project. This expects the compiler to interpret a hexadecimal color and fails the build. (this was my problem)

Hope this helps.
er... Happy debugging??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Ant is 1.8.0 or later version. Cordova 3.3 demands that.

Answer (score 0):

In the past several days, I found that the conflicting files from Dropbox had a very long name. After renaming it, everything worked.